# Second Largest Value in Calculated Column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking to get the second last login for a user from the AccessLog Power BI Table. Using a calculated column to get the last login in the ApplicationUSer table, but also need the second to last login, in a calculated column, if it exists otherwise set to default date. ApplicationUser table is linked to the ApplicationAccessLog table via userid.

```
Lastest Access Date =
VAR Ho =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'ApplicationAccessLog'[LoginDate] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( HO ), 0, HO )
```

What is the best way to get the second largest value?

The max login and max -1 login needs to be less than or equal to the selected date of my report page as well, so thinking now towards a measure now. If that Selected date is the 25th Dec, then the max login needs to be from the 25th Dec or before and the same with max login -1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of functions you can rank values with, `RANK.EQ` / `RANKX` or `TOPN`.

Here's an attempt with the latter:

```
2ndToLast = MINX ( TOPN ( 2, 'Log', 'Log'[LoginDate] ), 'Log'[LoginDate] )
```

This returns the top two rows sorted by `LoginDate` and then selects the minimal `LoginDate` from those two rows that `TOPN` returns.

Comment: This dint work for me, couldnt figure out why. But another inspired command worked:

2ndToLast = MAXX ( FILTER( 'Log', 'Log'[LoginDate]<>MAX( 'Log'[LoginDate])), 'Log'[LoginDate] )

Comment: @VjayalakshmiK That's not bad but doesn't generalize nicely to nth-to-last for n > 2. I just added another answer that uses the recently-added INDEX function.

Answer (score 2):

Power BI [recently added](https://pbidax.wordpress.com/2022/12/15/introducing-dax-window-functions-part-1/) new window functions: [OFFSET](https://dax.guide/offset/), [INDEX](https://dax.guide/index/), and [WINDOW](https://dax.guide/window/).

Using INDEX is probably the best way to do this now:

```
2ndToLast = INDEX ( 2, ALL ( 'Log'[LoginDate] ), ORDERBY ('Log'[LoginDate], DESC ) )
```